# VBA in Mac: Create PowerPoint Slide for Each Row in Excel Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I am absolutely new to VBA. I am trying to create a presentation such that content of each cell (in a row) creates a new slide in the presentation.

I searched for the code, but I could only find it for Windows. When I am trying to use the code on Mac - OS X 10.7.4 (Excel 2011), I am getting an error.

Need help :)!

Code and error are as follows:

**Code:**

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFTWn.png) converted to text:

```
Sub OneSlideForEachRowCell()
'Open the Excel workbook. Change the filename here.
Dim OWB As New Excel.Workbook
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open{":Users:vikshek:Desktop:list.xlsx")
'Grab the first Worksheet in the Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Set WS = OWB.Worksheets(1)
'Loop through each used row in Column A
For i = 1 To WS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
  'Copy the first slide and paste at the end of the presentation
  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
  ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1)

  'Change the text of the first text box on the slide.
  ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next
End Sub
```

**Error:**

`Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object`

On debugging, it's highlighting the text

```
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=":Users:vikshek:Desktop:list.xlsx")
```

Comment: Copy your code into the question and then highlight it and use the "code" (`{}`) button in the editor to mark it as code, this will fix the formatting.

Comment: Also, see this MS KB: [You receive run-time error 429 when you automate Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/828550)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That link might help, but note that it's about Office 2003 and Vikram's trying to get this working on a Mac.  Vikram, as far as I know, COM automation (what you're trying to do) is only supported in Windows Office.  You'll probably need to use Applescript instead.  Check Ron DeBruin's site for lots of good Mac/VBA workarounds: http://www.rondebruin.nl/

Answer (score 1):

The path name must include the volume name. Try the complete path name for the file, for example:

```
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Macintosh HD:Users:vikshek:Desktop:list.xlsx")`
```

Try the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) path name of the file which does not need the volume name, although this form may not work before Excel 2013.

`/Users/vikshek/Desktop/list.xlsx`

## Reference

See [Performing File and Folder Operations Programmatically in Excel 2011 for the Mac](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614412(v=office.14).aspx) for examples using Applescript (with the MacScript function) and VBA.